# Function it is not binded to the event

Tags: javascript, marionette

I am learning to Backbone.Marionette and this is an attempt to create a simple application where I am displaying some text on button click.

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8jq3H/3/).

JS:

```
var MyApp = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

MyApp.addRegions({
    mainRegion: "#container"
});

MyAppModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    putText: function(){
        $("#container").html("Here is some text.");
    }
});

MyAppCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: MyAppModel
});

MyAppItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    events: {
        'click #button': 'putText'
    }
});

MyAppCompositeView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    // not sure what to mention here    
});

MyApp.start();
```

The text is not being displayed and there is no error in the console.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot understand what is your goal here.

First you don't have a template through which an `ItemView` "draws" on screen. Second, your event is captured in the wrong place. It's the `MyAppItemView` itself that should capture the event (and then could also update the model). In my sample, for example, `Hello` is appended to the DOM. The model and collection are not used.

Here a simple working example (http://jsfiddle.net/3G9Ls/3/) forked by **Derick Bailey** one (http://jsfiddle.net/derickbailey/M5J8Q/). The latter use a more complete structure and should be the way to go.

```
// HTML

<div id="container"></div>

<script type="text/html" id="sample-template">
    <button id="button">Button</button>
</script>

// JS

var MyApp = new Marionette.Application();

MyApp.addRegions({
    "mainRegion": "#container"
});

MyAppItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({    
    template: "#sample-template",

    events: {
        "click #button": "appendText" 
    },

    appendText: function() {
        $("#container").append("Hello");
    }
});

MyApp.addInitializer(function(){
    MyApp.mainRegion.show(new MyAppItemView());
});

MyApp.start();
```

I really suggest to read the documentation of Marionette. You can also see/buy **David Sulc** book at [Backbone.Marionette.js: A Gentle Introduction](https://leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction) to grasp the main concepts behind Marionette.